# метод compareTo для сравнения по полю LocalDate

Tags: java

Хочу реализовать интерфейс  Comparable, и с помощью него произвести сравнение (и последующую сортировку) элементов массива по полю типа LocalDate. Приведенный ниже код дает ошибку dateOfAdmission cannot be resolved or is not a field. Мне посоветовали читать справку с оракла https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDate.html, но из-за того что мой английский пока что состоит из бед и огорчений, понял я немного. Прошу объяснить мне в чем ошибка и как нужно сделать, что бы я смог сравнивать объекты по полю типа LocalDate. Заранее благодарен.
*p.s.: клонирование не дописано*

```
package myDefault;
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;


/*В данной программе ставлю целью повторить пройденный материал по сравнению и клонированию объектов*/

public class Student implements Comparable<LocalDate>, Cloneable
{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
LocalDate dateOfAdmission;
int scholarship;

Student(String firstName, String lastName, int day, int month, int year, int scholarship)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    dateOfAdmission = LocalDate.of(day,month,year);
    this.scholarship = scholarship;
}

public int compareTo(LocalDate other)
{
    return Double.compare(dateOfAdmission, other.dateOfAdmission); 
}

public void fillArray()
{
    Student[] arrayOfStudents = new Student[3];
    Student petya = new Student("Petya","Popov",10,6,2017,1500);
    Student vasya = new Student("Vasya","Ovsyannikov",5,6,2017,1500);
    Student gena = new Student("Gena","Lolov",12,6,2017,1500);

    arrayOfStudents[0] = petya;
    arrayOfStudents[1] = vasya;
    arrayOfStudents[2] = gena;
}

public void createNewArray()
{
    Student[] newArray = new Student[3];
}

public void outputArray(Student[] arrayOfStudents)
{
    int counter;
    for(counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
    {
        System.out.println(arrayOfStudents[counter]);
    }
}

public Student clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
{
    Student cloned = (Student) super.clone();
    return cloned;
}
```

}

Comment: А разве `LocalDate` сравнивает как `Double`? Вы сами должны написать сравнение этих полей и вывести `0,1,-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сами должны реализовать сравнение двух полей а не позаимствовать чужой. Можно конечно и чужой позаимствовать если он вам подходит. Мне кажется что дабл вам никак не подходит. Попробуйте как то так:

```
int compareTo (LocalDate otherDate) {
    int cmp = (year - otherDate.year);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        cmp = (month - otherDate.month);
        if (cmp == 0) {
            cmp = (day - otherDate.day);
        }
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

Но это компаратор для `LocalDate` а вам нужен для студента по этому

```
int compareTo (Student otherStudent) {
    LocalDate otherDate = otherStudent.dateOfAdmission;
    int cmp = (year - otherDate.year);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        cmp = (month - otherDate.month);
        if (cmp == 0) {
            cmp = (day - otherDate.day);
        }
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

Это будет компаратор студентов, НО сравнивать он будет только по дате!